# Uploading a picture in django to a unique folder

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm fairly new to Django and am having a bit of trouble trying to upload images

So broadly, I have a user class:

```python
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    user_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
```

And a profile class:

```python
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=<PATH>, blank=True, default=get_default_profile_image)
```

For the above PATH in profile, I tried to upload it to:
**'profiles/' + user.user_id + '/image.png'**

But if I try to do that, it says "AttributeError: 'OneToOneField' object has no attribute 'user_id'"

Is there any way to set the upload_to path as **profiles/user_id/image.png** where the user_id will be the unique id of that user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a *callable* to the [**`upload_to=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to), so we can work with:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    def photo_upload(self, filename):
        return f'profiles/{self.user.user_id}/{filename}'
    
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=photo_upload,
        blank=True,
        default=get_default_profile_image
    )
```